# Edit existing excel file with laravel excel or php

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I am working on a project where a user can upload an excel file with multiple sheets.

Now I just need to append some rows in one of the sheets and download that file.

I am using [laravel excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) version 3.0 for that. I tried to import the excel file first which gives me the collection of all the sheets and now I am just exporting them with the same collection (after updating the specific sheet).

This works fine for the data but loses all the styling and formatting in other sheets.

I just want to know that is there any way to achieve this without losing the styling and formatting of other sheets.

Here is my code.

```
   // this gives me data in the collection
        $defaultData = Excel::toCollection(new EvaluationSheetImport, storage_path('app/public/evaluation_data.xlsx'));

        // it returns the sheet without styling
        Excel::queue(new AssessmentSheetExport($defaultData), 'evaluation_databaseExport.xlsx',  'public');
```

Comment: same problem can anyone solve it